# Tab, space and enter keys not working in vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, adk

when i run run flutter in vs code the enter, tab and space keys not working properly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); //my cursor is in center of the brackets
  }
}
```

When i press enter my cursor cannot come to the next line. Similarlly the tab key and space key also not working.

Answer (score 1):

My issue with the Keyboard (enter, tab, space, backspace, etc) vs. VS Code started after I installed some extensions. After some further investigation, VIM extension was the reason, at least the version 1.25., from 'vscodevim' supplier. Try to uninstall such extension and restart your VS COde. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g3z3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just go to vscode settings and search `format` .

Select `Also modified in Dart > User`, beside the `Format On Save`  &   `Format On Type` ,  and turn them `OFF`

Solved the issue for me

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with me just a before `tab` was not working and I solved it just pressing
`ctrl+m` shortcut on Windows.

Comment: please make sure to explain more so people can understand why the actual problem is happening